# Include HTML into another HTML

Tags: html

Is there a way to include one html to another in a dropdown menu without using files I know that it can be done, if we save one html at a path and try to access it using a java script. but I want both HTML to be in the same script.
Html sample looks something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want whole html pages or hidden html fragments?

Comment: A javascript solution ? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: so If  need another html say volvo is that html which has some html content in it,  with this what we can do is save volvo.html at a location and give that path into the option value like this " <option value="volvo.html">Volvo</option>" right. but instead of doing that I want the html inside volvo to be included in this html like  " <option value=<html>.....</html>>Volvo</option>"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can make a data property to fetch the files separately:
[W3Schools - How To Include](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

*To be fair, you could update that example, by using fetch, instead of XMLHttpRequest, but hey, it works :-P*

Or you if you just want to show or hide elements, you can do so with CSS, and a little JS, like this:

```
 function show(){
  document.getElementById(event.target.value).style.display ='block';
 }
 function hide(){
  document.getElementById(event.target.value).style.display ='none';
 }
 object.onselect = function(){myScript(};
```